# How can i reirect to my welcome page in facebook after clicking like button in facebook

Tags: facebook

I have facebook fan page. and i also created a fbml tab which i have as the default tab for my facebook page. Now when someone clicks on the like button on my page it takes to the Wall. Is there anyway we can get it to show the FBML instead of the wall after clicking the like button.

Thanks

Prady

Answer (score 1):

Not really a stackoverflow question imo, but click settings on your main page, there you can select the default landing page.

Comment: Oh!!... i am sorry if its not a stackoverflow question.. But is there a setting to default the fbml tab when like button is clicked. i have the default landing tab as my welcome tab. the only problem is when i click the like button it take to my wall. i need this to stay on my welcome tab after i click the like button